# Cask 'google-chrome-canary' is unavailable

Tags: macos, google-chrome, homebrew

I've tried several ways to install Google Chrome Canary in macOS using [Brew](https://brew.sh/)

`brew install chrome-canary`

> Error: No similarly named formulae found.
> Error: No available formula or cask with the name "chrome-canary".

`brew install --cask google-chrome-canary`

> Error: Cask 'google-chrome-canary' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

`brew cask install google-chrome-canary`

> Error: Calling brew cask install is disabled! Use brew install [--cask] instead.

All of them failed. How to install Google Chrome Canary in the latest macOS using the latest `brew` version?

Answer (score 14):

The solution is:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions && brew install --cask google-chrome-canary
```

Working using `Homebrew 2.7.1`